# How to pass a character field from a select to a function

Tags: apex

I'm trying to get the CPFs (set of characters) of each contact from my select and send these CPFs to a function that will return these CPFs with a certain formatting, but I'm not getting it, I keep getting the error "Attempt to de-reference a null object", I need to print these CPFs formatted in a vfp. If anyone can identify where I'm going wrong or have a better suggestion on how I can do this I'd appreciate it

```
public with sharing class DadosNotaPromissoriaController {
    public transient DadosNotaPromissoriaVF_VO ntPromissoria  {get; set;}
    public List <OpportunityContactRole> avalista {get;set;}
    public String idOpp {get; set;}
    public List <String> cpfcontact {get; set;}
    public List <String> cpfProcurador {get; set;}
    public Integer bemSize  {get; set;}
    
    public String formatacpf (String cpf){
        return cpf.substring(0, 3) + '.' +
            cpf.substring(3, 6) + '.' +
            cpf.substring(6, 9) + '-' +
            cpf.substring(9, 11);
    }
    
     public List <OpportunityContactRole> getAvalist(){ 
         if(avalista==null){
             avalista=[SELECT Id,contactId,contact.CPF__c
                       FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                       WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpp
                      ];
         }  
        Integer j=0;
        for(OpportunityContactRole i: avalista){
           cpfcontact[j]=formatacpf(avalista[j].contact.CPF__c);
           System.debug('avalista[j].contact.CPF__c' + avalista[j].contact.CPF__c); 
           j++;
           }
         return avalista;
        }
```

When commenting out the line:" cpfcontact[j]=formatacpf(guarantor[j].contact.CPF__c);
"
[image]

Comment: When you post an error, pl include stacktrace. In this case, stacktrace will tell you exact line number at issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is at below line of code.

```
cpfcontact[j]=formatacpf(avalista[j].contact.CPF__c);
```

Here the field `cpfcontact` is not initialized so will be `null` by default. You could initialize before for loop or during class field initialization as below.

```
public with sharing class DadosNotaPromissoriaController {
    public transient DadosNotaPromissoriaVF_VO ntPromissoria  {get; set;}
    public List <OpportunityContactRole> avalista {get;set;}
    public String idOpp {get; set;}
    public List <String> cpfcontact {get; set;}
    public List <String> cpfProcurador {get; set;}
    public Integer bemSize  {get; set;}
    
    public String formatacpf (String cpf){
        return cpf.substring(0, 3) + '.' +
            cpf.substring(3, 6) + '.' +
            cpf.substring(6, 9) + '-' +
            cpf.substring(9, 11);
    }
    
     public List <OpportunityContactRole> getAvalist(){ 
         if(avalista==null){
             avalista=[SELECT Id,contactId,contact.CPF__c
                       FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                       WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpp
                      ];
         }
        cpfcontact = new List<String>();  
        Integer j=0;
        for(OpportunityContactRole i: avalista){
           cpfcontact[j]=formatacpf(avalista[j].contact.CPF__c);
           System.debug('avalista[j].contact.CPF__c' + avalista[j].contact.CPF__c); 
           j++;
           }
         return avalista;
        }
```

Look for line `cpfcontact = new List<String>();`

Comment: Thank you for your help! @metasync